# Find closest matching array in SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I think I may be missing something conceptually or in my wording, because I can't seem to find what I need.

Each user will have an array of, say 20 items, like

```
array(123,482,836,496,etc)
```

And will hopefully find another user who has the most matching elements. I assume I won't have to loop through and make a bunch of queries.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I'll post my final code when I get it going, for anyone else.

Comment: How is the data stored ? Raw array or in database ?

Comment: Was thinking the same but if the data are stored in the database, not the same approach

Comment: @JesusTheHun I haven't built this yet, just figuring it out. I will do whatever is fastest, which I assumed would be a raw array in the database. Comparing arrays in sql, rather than reading them into php.

Comment: Though your question is "valid" it is off topic for Stack Overflow as you are requesting an opinionated recommendation that is not concise for our format. To help you out I recommend that you attempt on of the above suggested methods, and then edit your question with your attempted code snippet. As it stands this question is most likely to get closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise I was thinking about this wrong, Andreas helped me on the right track. Instead of having an array for each user in the database like `$user1 = array(12,18,34)`, we store each pair like so:

```
USER  |  VALUE
1     |  12
1     |  18
1     |  34
2     |  15
2     |  18
2     |  38
```

Say I am `$user3`, and want to find which user shares most values with me `12` `17` `42` I can loop through each of my values, running a query to save all users with the same value.

```
SELECT user FROM table WHERE value = $user3[0]; //save into $array1
```

Doing that for each value will only be three queries in this example. I'll be left with a set of matching users for each query, `$array1` `$array2` `$array3`. I can then use the `array_intersection` function on those arrays to find which user comes up the most.

Comment: Was me a pleasure ;) Upvote and/or accept would be nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

[array_intersect — Computes the intersection of arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Could I run this command in PHP without first having to read all users from SQL into PHP?

Comment: No, this is not a sql function :) You need to get the data from your DB

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick on php side, if you have arrays for both users.

```
$arr1 = array (1, 3, 5, 7);
$arr2 = array (1, 2, 5, 9);
$same = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2); 

print_r($same); // Returns array(1, 5);
```

It returns the intersection of both arrays. See http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: Trouble is, I will have potentially thousands of users in the database, and was hoping for SQL to do the comparing, rather than PHP have to read and process each user

Comment: How are those IDs/values stored in your DB? I think comparison in DB is very hard. But have a look [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/intersect.php). Maybe this helps, but i think that the values that meet the intersection have to be euqal.

Comment: I haven't coded anything yet, I'm trying to figure out how to begin. I will potentially have thousands of users, so I want to avoid reading them all into PHP. If you have a way of storing them in SQL that would be optimal, I'd be glad to hear it. Or maybe I should change the way I store this data to not use arrays... thinking...

Comment: And, if performance is important to you, a good question will be: Do this script needs to execute often ? Or can you just make a cron job once a hour, and serve results in static mode ?

Comment: It's the main function of the website, comparing large quantities of data sets. Each set will be small, but there will be thousands I want to match by similarity. It doesn't have to be an array, if there's a better way of organizing the data that you can think of.

Comment: You can store those values in a table bound to the user ID. Each `value` `user` pair one row. Then you can `SELECT user FROM table WHERE value=wanted_value`. So you can get all users with a specific value

Answer (score 0):

u can use array_uintersect

```
<?php
function myfunction($v1,$v2) 
{
  if ($v1===$v2)
  {
    return 0;
  } 
  return 1;
}
$a1=array(1, 2, 4);
$a2=array(1, 3, 4);
print_r(array_uintersect($a1,$a2,"myfunction")); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one, though this maybe a long method:

```
$array1 = array("5","26","38","42");

$array2 = array("15","36","38","42");

$final_array = array();

foreach($array1 as $key=>$val){
    if(in_array($val,$array2)){
        $final_array[] = $val;
    }
}

print_r($final_array);
```

> Result: Array ( [0] => 38 [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) => 42 )

Other way you can use [array_intersect method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```